# Decrypt / Encrypt connection string in web.config in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a connection string in web.config which custom-encrypted.

I would like to decrypt this during application start (the first page is Login page which is based on a Master page. The login credentials are verified using the encrypted connection string) and it ***must*** be encrypted before application closes - by whatever way - either normal close or application error.

I tried to implement using Global.asax but since any changes to web.config restarts application, it went into a loop and hence gave up this method.

Please note that I do not want the default configuration encryption provided by ASP.NET as I use a custom one.

While it is easy to decrypt the connection string during startup, is there really any way to encrypt again during application close?

Many thanks!

Comment: Isn't that what SSL was made for?

Comment: No. I dont use https. I forgot to mention I use Session.

Comment: Store it somewhere else (App_Data folder for example).

Comment: What's "application close"? If I turn the power off, how will you be able to encrypt something?

Comment: Good point :) I never went to this deep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to risk this as an answer because I can't really see the need for what you describe:

1. If the connection string is already encrypted in the web.config *_you_don't_need_to_decrypt_it* when the application starts, you just decrypt it every time you instantiate a database connection. Believe me, the performance of decrypting the connection string is negligible even if you do it every time you open a connection. But assuming you are a performance freak and you only want to decrypt it once and put in Session (bad idea, but it appears that that's what you are doing), there's nothing to worry about as I will explain in point 3 below.
2. Supposing that you decrypt it once (Application_Start, what have you), why do you say that you need to encrypt it again `before application closes - by whatever way - either normal close or application error.`? The connection string **is not** transferred over the wire, it's something that it's used on the **server side** in order to instantiate a connection to the database but it is not something that someone can see by using the application, unless of course, you store it in ViewState but that would be very silly.
3. You mentioned that you store something in Session although is not 100% clear whether you are referring to the connection string or something else. Assuming it is the connection string (again, I can't think of a valid reason for this. I apologize if there's one.) it's not something that any user can see since Session is nothing but memory bytes **on the server**. The same applies for Cache.

So, that's that.

You decrypt the connection string, instantiate your connection, do your thing and close the connection. The connection string can stay encrypted in web.config for ever; untouched.

**UPDATE**

Since the OP is using the Membership provider, the solution is to implement your own Membership provider. You can download a sample project demonstrating how to do this from Microsoft at the following link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi

Look at the `SQLConnectionHelper.cs` class.

[Here's another post](http://williablog.net/williablog/post/2008/05/02/Setting-Membership-Profile-Role-providers-connection-string-at-runtime.aspx) doing pretty much exactly what you need.

**UPDATE 2**

Here's another way to do the same thing using Reflection. Call it a hack, but it seems to do the job:

Inside `Application_PreRequestHandler`  in `Global.asax` call this method, where `connectionString` is your connection string already decrypted:

```
private void SetProviderConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
// Set private property of Membership, Role and Profile providers. Do not try this at home!!
var connectionStringField = Membership.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (connectionStringField != null)
                connectionStringField.SetValue(Membership.Provider, connectionString);

            var roleField = Roles.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (roleField != null)
                roleField.SetValue(Roles.Provider, connectionString);

            var profileField = ProfileManager.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (profileField != null)
                profileField.SetValue(ProfileManager.Provider, connectionString);
}
```

[Source.](http://forums.asp.net/p/997608/2209437.aspx)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the connection string is implicitly used by Membership class (System.Web.Security). If I were to use the connection string, I can surely decrypt in code, but this is something used by FCL and I think I have no control over it.

Comment: Elaborate more on `implicitly used by Membership class` and explain what FCL is, please. In regards to the Membership class, didn't you say that you provide your own encryption? If the Membership class uses it implicitly, there must be place, somewhere in your code, where you can hook into to decrypt the connection string before the Membership class can use it; otherwise, how's the Membership class going to know how to decrypt it?

Comment: @Sathya I think I know what FCL is: Framework Class Library. Correct?

Comment: OK.. here is the complete scenario. I use a DB, which is used for both core application and also AspNetSqlMembershipProvider. Now, Login is the landing page and credentials are verified using Membership.ValidateUser method. Hope you are aware that for using AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, we need to provide a connection string, which should be encrypted as per my requirement. Though I can decrypt it in Login.aspx before validating the user, in case of user closes the browser or some error occurs, the connection string is left decrypted in web.config, which I cannot afford.

Comment: Icarus, thanks for all your solutions! Will try which best suits me.